# Is there a way to add NTLM authentication using oracle SOA(to invoke a rest service) in JDeveloper 12c(12.2.1)?

Tags: oracle, soa, jdeveloper

Is there a way to add NTLM authentication using oracle SOA(to invoke a rest service) in JDeveloper 12c(12.2.1). I am trying to call Dynamics CRM rest service from soa12c